# Null checking complex parameter in Controller action ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding

I would like to listen advice how can I check null easier.

Here's my sample code.

```
public class SaveFileInfo
{
    public int FileNo { get; set; }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
public string UploadList(DataValue repositoryData, SaveFileInfo incompleteFile = null)
{
}
```

First, I tried simple check object is null, but it did not work because default model binder create instance and set value every request.

```
if(incompleteFile == null)
{
...
}
```

So currently I checked each variable is null in parameter

```
if(incompleteFile.FileNo == 0 && incompleteFile.FilePath == null)
{
...
}
```

Unfortunately sample code have a few properties, real code have many properties, I can not check  property value.

Custom model binder may not recommend as I know, is there simple way of null checking complex parameter?

Comment: Apply the `[Required]` attribute to the property? The model state will validate and return the response with validation errors.

Comment: @YongShun Hello. It just a simplify code, currently code not uses Model or ModelStates

Comment: Does all property is required ? Which property you want to be null and which are not? Could you please clarify that?

Comment: Sounds weird that you want to validate properties but without the ModelState which this feature already built.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Hello. I revised missing code. There is two paramters and repositoryData is required object parameter and not null, incompleteFile is optional paramter. So I declared set to null but it always initialized by default model binder

Comment: @YongShun Yes currently manually checking model values :D

Comment: In that case, probably you need the Reflection to iterate each property in the model class and check its value is not null. This assumes that you want to **validate every property**. If you want to validate certain properties not all, still I would recommend using the DataAnnotation and ModelState.

Comment: Side note: Prefer `is null` over `== null`.  Taking your sample code as an example, `incompleteFile.FileNo == null` is a redundant test because an `int` is a value type and can't be null - using `is null` on a value type will not compile. (error CS0037: Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type)

Comment: Do you want to use `[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof())]` to validate your model?

Comment: @ZoharPeled FileNo has 0, because default model binder initalize default value of type. So int has 0

Comment: @shunman how is that related to my comment? Of course it would be 0 since that's the default value of int

Comment: @ZoharPeled Hello Zohar Peled thank you for  your review. I revised sample code null to 0

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I'm looking for way of code side, not declaration attributes along our team rules.  If not exists simple resolutions, I have no idea :D

Comment: What insane team rules do you work with? Everybody uses `[Required]` because that's what it is for. Why is your team trying to invent new, incompatible ways of solving already solved problems?

Comment: @TanveerBadar _" Everybody uses [Required]"_ - Erm no. I know at least one Team outside OP's that explicitly does not use those. That Team I am speaking of uses FluentValidation instead. To which project I am not affiliated. I am also not argueing for/against their reasoning, just stating what they do without judgement.

Comment: @Fildor And how exactly is fluent validation different than data annotations on a conceptual level? OP is talking about writing imperative code in each and every action. Fluent validation is nothing like that. I forgot for a moment in my original comment that if you are not pedantically correct on stack overflow, you are wrong. I won't bother engaging in this conversation any further.

Comment: It's different in that it doesn't pollute the dto class with annotations which is specifically mentioned by OP in comments. But yeah of course you are entitled to your temper issues :D

Comment: Hey guys finally I Figured out to solve this issue easily, sending blank object parameter same as server side model before request. Now then model parameter's properties are have null values